# Is Rodriguez's representation of the Laguerre polynomials defined $L_n^k(x)= \frac{e^xx^{-k}}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x}x^{n+k})$?

Tags: calculus, laguerre-polynomials

$$L_n^k(x)= \cfrac{e^xx^{-k}}{n!}\cfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x}x^{n+k})$$

Comment: I think I have almost proven it but I don't know how to continue or maybe I can't continue because I'm trying to deduce a definition.